# Почему не отправляется письмо?

Tags: javascript, php, обработка-ошибок

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка? При попытке отправить письмо выдает "Произошла ошибка!" и письмо не отправляется. Благодарю за помощь!

```html
<form name="MyForm" action="" id="callbacks" class="feedback_form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="Как к вам обращаться?" required>
  <input type="text" name="email" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Проконсультируйте меня" id="feedback_submit">
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('[name="MyForm"]').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    var title = $(form).next();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://мойсайт.рф/feedback/sendmail.php",
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      error: function() {
        title.html("Произошла ошибка!");
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        title.html("Отправляем данные...");
      },
      success: function(result) {
        title.html(result);
        checkThis();
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Файл sendmail.php:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
      $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
      $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if ($name == "" or $email == "") {
      echo "Заполните, пожалуйста, все поля!";
    } else {
      $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
      $to = "мояпочта@mail.ru";
      $subject = "Заявка с сайта!";
      $headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8; \r\nReply-To: <$email> \n";
      $headers .= "From: Моя компания <мояпочта@mail.ru>";
      $message = "Имя: $name\r\nE-mail: $email\r\nIP отправителя: $ip"; 
      $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

      if ($send == true) {
        echo "Ваше письмо отправлено!<br>В ближайшее время мы Вам перезвоним.<br>Спасибо что выбрали нас!";
      } else {
        echo "Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!";
      }
    }
  }
  ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On'); 
?>
```

Comment: Используйте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-get-last.php для получения информации об ошибке.

Comment: Ты видишь это сообщение потому что отработал этот участок кода на клиенте error:function(){title.html("Произошла ошибка!");},. Судя по всему аякс получил 500 ошибку от сервера. Нужно смотреть логи сервера или дебажить код который обрабатывает пост для http://мойсайт.рф/feedback/sendmail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите ваш обработчик `error` в такой вид

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Произошла ошибка! " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
}
```

и посмотрите какая именно ошибка происходит.

И вам урок на будущее - не нужно глотать оригинальные ошибки.

Вот здесь

> ```
> echo "Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!";
> ```

У вас будет та же самая проблема, если вы не зафиксируете исходную ошибку

Comment: @LADYX попробуйте `title.html()` заменить на `alert()` или `console.log()`. Или `title.text()`

Comment: @LADYX "Глотание" это когда вы детальный диагноз от врача заменяете фразой "Я заболел". Возможно кому-то ваш диагноз и не интересен, но в аптеке без диагноза лекарство вы не получите